# Conditional merging of cells in excell

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

EDIT: I've found a solution through creating two SPSS datasets; one with variables 2 and 3 and one file with variable 4 and merging the files. However, a function in Excel would be more elegant.

I have been looking around for a solution, but I haven't been able to find one. 
I've obtained datapoints through time from 1982 until 2017 which I want to plot. However, the data needs to be interpolated and I've made long series of the same series, with delta T of a day (might be altered on a later moment).

What I want to do: create column 5 which contains entries from column 3 if the date in column 4 matches a corresponding date in column 2.

[image: A screenshot of the dataset]

I was wondering whether there's a merging function for this?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you want, but I'm guessing that maybe another column 5 would contain entries from column 3 if the date in column 4 matches a corresponding date in column 2? And I presume you mean _interpolated_, not _extrapolated_. Otherwise, I can't make sense of your question.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Sorry for the vague description.

Comment: Assuming the first data point in column 4 is cell D3, then in E3: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D3,$B$3:$C$nn,2,FALSE),"")` and fill down.  "nn" is the row number of the last row of your data.  This will fill in the data where there is a matching date and leave a blank elsewhere.

Comment: Please post your answer below, not as an update to your question.

Comment: @Bandersnatch thanks; that's it! How do I mark the question as answered?

Comment: Glad to help.  I'll post it as an answer, and you can click on the up arrow.  If you see a check mark, you can click on that to accept the answer, but you may not have enough rep points yet.  I think it takes 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the first data point in column 4 is cell D3, then in E3:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D3,$B$3:$C$nn,2,FALSE),"")
```

and fill down. Here "nn" is the row number of the last row of your data.

This will fill in the data where there is a matching date and leave a blank elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the columns are (`B`, `C`, `D` and `E`) for (`2`, `3`, `4` and `5`), the following formula will work in `E1`:

```
=INDIRECT("C"&MATCH(D1,B:B,0))
```

Now copy this cell and select the rest of the column from row 2 to the last row where there is an entry in `D`, then paste. Each row in `E` will contain a similar formula, but referring to the entry in the same row of `D`.

Entries for which there is no corresponding date will show as unavailable, which seems appropriate. These can later be overwritten with interpolated data.